# how to get.Slice() to work with knockout observable values?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use .slice() to return values depending on the pagenumber that the user is on, however it doesn't update my list and displays no values in my UI, however it does output the right values to the console when I log the array.

I've tried to use .slice() with constant values like 0 and 10 and it works with them.

```
self.start = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.page_number() * self.emp_per_page();
});
self.end = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.page_number() * self.emp_per_page() + self.emp_per_page();
});

self.filteredEmployees = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.searchFilter().slice(self.start(), self.end());
});

console.log(self.filteredEmployees());
```

there are no error messages, just no results show on the UI

screenshot of console + empty list:
[image: screenshot of console + empty list:]

Comment: Is `searchFilter` the `observableArray` you are trying to get a chunk from? Does `page_number`  start from 0 or 1?

Comment: yes `searchFilter` is an observable array, and `page_number` starts at 0

Comment: If it's a regular array, why do you have a `()` after `self.searchFilter`?

Comment: I accidentally said it was a regular array it's actually observable. My mistake

Comment: I have created a basic pagination fiddle with your code. Click on the page numbers to test. Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/tz9dvxb8/

Comment: Thanks for that, it's very strange as my code is identical, it must be an underlying problem I just can't see what it is. I'll link a screenshot in the question to show the console, which shows the correct results, and the table which is empty. Again, the table is populated if I use constant values.

Comment: Can't make out much from the screenshot of the array. Either modify the the fiddle I created with some of your HTML or create a [working stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: I have fixed it, my results per page dropdown was written incorrectly and kept resetting the value of self.end() after the fact and It wasn't logging to the console, thank you anyway!